# OpenLayers text label overlap even with padding

Tags: gis, openlayers

Ol docs state that Padding can be used on text labels for decluttering.  [ol/style/Text](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text.html),

However my labels are still overlapping even when I indicate Padding.

Live example on codepen:  https://codepen.io/sjvmarigerr/pen/oNNVMXb?editors=1010

Style Function:

```
  function styleFunction (feature) {
   return new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: feature.get('PORT_NAME'),
        padding: [3, 3, 3, 3],
        font: "bold 15px sans-serif"
    })
  });};
```

Comment: I now see that padding is used in conjuction with "declutter" vector layer option to force more labels to be hidden by adding a padding buffer to the labels.


Is there any way in OpenLayers to offset labels instead of hiding them when there is overlap??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the declutter option??? If not give it a try, it might solve your problem. 
To do so, replace your vector layer config from this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction
      });
```

To this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction,
        declutter: true
      });
```

Remember that declutter should hide label if overlapping and will show label when zoom level is enough for not overlapping.

Comment: We don't want to hide labels at all.

According to docs, padding adds "pixels around the text for decluttering".

Even when I increase the padding to [100, 100, 100, 100], there is no padding adding at any zoom level.

Comment: I was assuming the padding would act like CSS and ensure no overlap, but I now understand it is possibly just used in conjuction with "declutter" option in vector layer to force more labels to be hidden.

Comment: @sjvmari padding is also used in conjunction with backgroundFill and backgroundStroke but on its own it has no effect.

Comment: I think we all agree that the current documentation of ol in this matter is highly confusing at least, if not outright misleading

Answer (score 0):

Due to zoom level i really don't see a way it will not overlap, but to make it more visible you can try the example below.

https://codepen.io/gpproton/pen/gOOEjJj?editors=1010

```
function styleFunction (feature) {
       return new ol.style.Style({
          text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: feature.get('PORT_NAME'),
            padding: [3, 3, 3, 3],
            font: "bold 11px sans-serif",
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#ffffff',
              width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#000'
            })
        })
      });
};
```

Comment: Actually I think I just realized the problem.   I was assuming the padding would act like CSS and ensure no overlap, but I think it is just used in conjuction with "declutter" option in vector layer to force more labels to be hidden.

Comment: It explains why padding wasn't working for me.   But hiding the label isn't the behavior I wanted though.   I was hoping there is a way to apply an offset or padding to labels if they overlap.   But it's a more complex feature to implement I assume